# Pass a parameter into an access report programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got an existing Access MDB.  I'm adding a command button to an existing Form that runs an existing report.  The change being made is that this button needs to pass in a parameter containing the ID of the record being reported on - currently the report runs on every record in the MDB.

I've altered the Query that the report runs on to use a parameter for the ID value, so that now when the button is clicked Access prompts for the record ID to report on, and the report displays like it should.

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass a parameter into the report for the query to use. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The DoCmd.OpenReport method has various arguments, one of which is a Where statement:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport"rptReport", acViewPreview,,"ID=" & Me.ID
```

That is

```
expression.OpenReport(ReportName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: AHA!  This is what I was looking for!  Thanks, Remou.

Comment: I'm using Access 2003, and the "WhereCondition" property is actually the 4th parameter, so you only need two commas in the example above, namely:
DoCmd.OpenReport"rptReport", acViewPreview,,"ID=" & Me.ID

Comment: This answer should be improved, to make the exclusion of a "FilterName" parameter less ambiguous. i.e. Since most Reports have an existing or embedded query, as the "Record Source", a "WhereCondition", is all that need be passed to the Report. The OpenArgs parameter is also overkill when used to open a Report, because it requires much more effort, to implement and is more often used with DoCmd.OpenForm.

Answer (score 4):

My general approach to this type of problem is to save the criteria in the database, typically a control table that has one row.  Then to reference your criteria you put a query in paranthesis that returns one value, of the criteria you want.  In your case, it would be something like:

```
(select reportID from control)
```

The advantage of this techinque is that the control table remembers the settings for the next time you run the report.  Of course, ReportID would be tied to a field in a form.  I also like the fact that your queries are isolated from forms; they can be run independently of forms.

Answer (score 2):

Why everyone wants to make this so complicated, I don't know.

1. save your report's recordsource without parameters.
2. as suggested by Remou, pass the criteria in the appropriate argument of DoCmd.OpenReport.

Trying to do it any other way is going to be a matter of resisting the natural methods for accomplishing tasks in Access.

Answer (score 2):

The Where clause of the docmd.openreport is a string that uses the same format as the where clause in a SQL statement.

The reason to put parameterize you query at the docmd instead of the RecordSource of the report is flexibility. You may have a need to open the report without any paremeter/return all the records or have the ability to filter on different fields.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this took me a bit.  Error was "Invalid use of parren" however the issue was the space in the field name.  I was creating a report from a db that someone did the common mistake, spaces.

To pass a param to a query through the where clause when the database field has a space use this example:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptByRegionalOffice", acViewPreview, , "[" & "Regional Office" & "]" & "=" & "'" & cmboOffices.Value & "'"
```

If you think about this you can see that this will produce `where [Regional Office]='string value'` just as you would expect in access sql.

Comment: You do an awful lot of unnecessary concatenation. All you really need is: "[Regional Office]='" & cmboOffices.Value & "'". And be careful if [Regional Office] can include the "'" character. It's normal in Access to use double quotes for strings, so: "[Regional Office]=" & Chr(34) & cmboOffices.Value & Chr(34)

Comment: Also, putting spaces in object names (as well as non-alphanumeric characters) is just something you should stop doing. Because you can, many people do it, but that's because they don't pay attention to the fact that the field name and its caption can be set separately, so a field RegionalOffice can have a Caption property of "Regional Office". This means that when you drop it on a form or report, it will automatically have the human-friendly caption (with spaces), while the field name is SQL-friendly (i.e., requires no brackets).