# How to collect input via a form and pass to report query in Access

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have an Access 2003 MDB where I would like to present a small form for the user to input two parameters "Start Date" and "End Date". Thanks to another Stack Overflow user ("Kevin Ross"), I learned how to embed the form control directly in the query that is used by the report I would like to display.

```
SELECT q1.CasesAssigned, q2.WarningsIssued  
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CasesAssigned 
    FROM vwCaseDetail 
    WHERE DateAssigned Between [Forms]![frmReporting]![txtStartDate] 
        AND [Forms]![frmReporting]![txtEndDate]) as q1,  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS WarningsIssued 
    FROM vwWarningDetail 
    WHERE DateIssued Between [Forms]![frmReporting]![txtStartDate] 
        AND [Forms]![frmReporting]![txtEndDate]) as q2
```

I have tried two different ways to open the report and pass the users input:

1. After the user enters parameters I call `DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview`. The problem here is that the reports opens and close so fast I never even see it. Ideally I would like to close the input collection form and then open the report.
2. Inside the `Report_Open` event I have code that opens the form that collect the users input. The input collection form opens, however I still get prompted by the report to enter in the two parameters. The report does not seem to be gathering the parameters from the input collection form.

Any suggestions on the proper way to pass data collected on a form to a report? Thank you.

Comment: Open the form before the report which depends on the form's values.  Add a command button to frmReporting whose click event is DoCmd.OpenReport.

Comment: @HansUp - Thanks! How would you determine if the report is loaded so you could go ahead and close the form that gathered the input for the report?

Comment: Why not just leave form open (hidden or minimized if desired) until report's Close event?  For that event you could do: `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmReporting"`  It might be useful to leave the form open instead ... to allow the user to re-run the report with a different date range selection.

Comment: @HansUp - Thanks a lot! That did the trick. I wish the SQL was simpler so I could just use a standard "WhereCondition" when opening the report. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I generally open the form to collect the filter conditions in the report's OnOpen event (and set the report's Recordsource according to the criteria selected in the filter form). That way, the form doesn't have to know anything about your report, and you don't have to muck about figuring out when and how to close the form after the report has been printed.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - So you would just recreate the SQL statement based on the user input and then set that as the recordsource of the report?

Comment: Yep. That's what I do all the time. But I also use other methods, such as storing the criteria in a class module, which makes it easier to bypass the filter form in the report's OnOpen event (check if the class instance is initialized, if it isn't, skip filtering). I try to make my reports usable in as many contexts as possible, which means not hardwiring them to any criteria or forms. However, the class module approach is really only justifiable when you have multiple reports that use a common set of filtering criteria. In that case, it's a real time-saver.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

The problem should be the logic of what your wantig. Why do you want a report calling a form? Why not a form in wich you fulfill the parameters then call the report?

You can perform your requisites in this way:

1. Create a form containing the fields corresponding to your desired parameters (Eg two textboxes called Param1 and Param2, in a form called Form1)
2. Create a query that retrieves the data for your report, referencing, in the conditions field, the parameters in the form (In the example, `[Forms]![Form1]![Param1]` and  `[Forms]![Form1]![Param2]`). Also, right clik on a empty space of query builder and select "parameters". Inform all the parameters (with the entire strings `[Forms]![Form1]![Param1]` and  `[Forms]![Form1]![Param2]`) with the correct data type. Let's call this query Query1
3. Create a report based on Query1. Lets call this report as Report1
4. Back to Form1, create a button (use the Wizard, its faster) for calling Report1.

Execute the Form1, in runtime fill the textboxes with the desired parameters then click the button. Make sure that you have data in your tables wich corresponds the Query.

In the other parts of your application, instead you call Report1 directly, call the Form1 that will manage Report1 querying and showing.

Comment: There are several good reasons for the report to call its own filtering form, not least of which is that you may want to offer different filtering options in different contexts where the report is run. Also, if you re-use the filter form in multiple locations, then the filter form doesn't have to know anything about the reports that use it. To me, it's much more logical to open the filter form as a dialog in the report's OnOpen event than it is to open the form and then chain to the report from there. Each to his own!