# MS Access Parameter Query inside Subform Won't Print

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here's what I've done:

I created a Parameter Query in which one of the crtiterias is Between [Start Date] and [End Date]. I then put that Parameter Query along with other bound fields and created a subform. So far, no problems and it works great.

But I'm having issues when it comes to printing or trying to convert the form into a PDF. As soon as I ask it to print, for example, the pop-ups from the parameter query will pop up asking me the dates again and even after I enter them in (again), it keeps asking me multiple times and cancels the print job.

How do I keep the query from essentially running when I'm trying to print what's on the screen? The same thing happens if I'm trying to create a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

In my not so humble opinion, parameters are handled badly in MS Access.

I think having to enter the values in the query whenever it is run (unless it is a one off experimental query) is just wrong headed. It would be so much easier to automate reports like that if you could just pass the parameters.

Typically, I create a report without the parameters in the where clause of the query, and then pass in your own where condition which gets added on [Remou's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398854/685)

You could also alter the query in the report before you call it, but that's pretty hackey.

-- Edit --

I see the confusion. I interpreted what you were doing as a report (not a form).

What's likely happening is you that when it tries to render/format the print job, it's having to make multiple calls to form's record source. And that why it keeps asking you for that data.

From what I understand in your question, you have a query that looks like this:

```
select foo 
from bar 
where 
    yaddah_date between [Start Date] and [End Date]
```

And then you've used that query as the record source for a form that you are trying to latter print as a PDF. First of all you should probably create a report that is an analogue of the form. And then open the report for printing with a filter on it:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", , , , _
                    "yaddah_date between " & txtStartDate & _
                        " and " & txtEndDate
```

(the last part is basically the filter/where clause that report will apply to the results of the query that's generating its data).

If you MUST print the form, you can do something similar

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "foo", acNormal, , _
                "yaddah_date between " & txtStartDate & _
                    " and " & txtEndDate
```

Or you can set the `filter` property of the form/subform.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked out the link you gave, but I'm a little unclear as to what this would do and where I would implement it. I'm not too familiar with implementing back-end solutions. Could you explain? Thank you!