# Run a report off a query automatically

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that runs from a form. That form uses a combo-box for the user to select a parameter that causes the query to run. What I would really like is to run a report off of that query automatically. Here's the event code I have to activate the query from the form:

```
Private Sub EmpName_AfterUpdate()

DoCmd.OpenQuery "TrainingRecords", acViewNormal, acEdit

DoCmd.Close acForm, "EmployeeTrainingRecords"

End Sub
```

More plain as to what it does now:

1. User opens form TrainingRecords
2. User selects name from combo-box
3. Query runs and displays a list of trainings completed by that employee
4. Form closes by itself

What I would like

1. User opens the form Training Records
2. User selects name from combo-box
3. User selects "Run" button
4. Form closes
5. User sees a report appear with a list of trainings completed by that employee

Obviously a query has to run somewhere in there but I'm not sure how to work out the query running to create the report without the user seeing everything going on.

Comment: Reports are linked to queries, and queries can get parameters from a user form.  There are tons of examples and tutorials out there; here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/398804/8112776 and some [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356?ocmsassetID=HA010096314&CorrelationId=47f6ffb2-6218-4017-9dab-7c8b5296241d&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB):

Comment: No more need to open query for report than there is for a form. Set the query as the report RecordSource. Instead of dynamic parameter in query I recommend using WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenReport method: `DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", acViewPreview, , "EmpID=" & Me.comboboxname`. Basic Access functionality.

Comment: @ashleedawg & @ June7 --  so is this a Duplicate Question, or would it make sense to put what you're saying - and the links - in an Answer because it's only a duplicate Answer ?

Comment: @MikeM - I hadn't looked closely enough at the link to know if it's actually a duplicate. I posted the link as a courtesy since I had them handy, but if you feel it [*meets **the criteria** to be considered a "duplicate"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/370758), by all means flag it (and if 4 other members agree with you, the question will be closed.)  Alternatively, if you have a few minutes to turn the comments from myself & June7 into **[a solid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**, then I'm sure it would be appreciated by the OP and others.

Comment: @June7 -- (tag↑)

Comment: @ashleedawg -- Thanks for your reply.  I've been trying to understand better what the community really thinks about these kind of things.  I think it definitely can have the exact same answer, but the question is coming from a different place;  I think they are talking about the same thing, but with a significantly different process behind it.  I feel like that makes it hard to call it a duplicate - but I feel guilty about making an answer that mostly explains how to use the other answer :-p.  But, indeed, maybe I'll do that after a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a parameter into an access report programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually quite on track.
You just need to change your idea a little bit...

The query doesn't need to come from the Form.  The Report can "own" the query and you just tell it to go. This includes being able to send your parameter value.

There are a number of ways to do this.  The link from the experienced folks in the Comments gives a really easy one...

- **DoCmd.OpenReport**

If you first make the report, ignoring any "Where" clause in its query, you can simply add a "Where" in DoCmd.OpenReport... 
they made it easy :-).

So the basic example is as:

```
'--- variable for holding the parameter ---
Dim strMyParameter As String

'--- Get the parameter value from a combobox on this current form ---
strMyParameter = Me.cbxMyComboBox.Value

'--- Use the value in opening the report in a new window ---
DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview, Null, "ID=" & strMyParameter, acWindowNormal, Null
```

where
 - the first argument is the name of your report in MS Access
 - the second is how you want to see it (I put as Print Preview above)
 - the third is an initial record *filter* clause, which I ignore with "Null"

- **and the fourth is our *Where* clause**, forcing a column named "ID" to match the value from the combobox.

-the fifth is a window state which you can leave as acWindowNormal for most cases
-and the last is a special arguments object you don't need for this, also ignored with "Null"

[Here is the MSDN page for this particular function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openreport-method-access).

[And here is the link to an SO page with almost but not quite the same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programatically), shared by @ashleedawg in the initial comments.
It includes lots of discussion and some other ways to do this, as well