# Show result from a query in a MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access with a table containing some values that have to be summed up by categories and those sums I have to sum up again with different weighting. Therefore I created a query looking like this:

```
SELECT Sum(expr1) AS expr1
FROM 
(SELECT 0.7 * Sum([performance]*[weighting])/100 AS expr1
FROM GOAL
WHERE GOAL.[ID]=[MYID] AND [YEAR]= [MYYEAR] and cat = "Cat1"
UNION 
SELECT 0.3 *Sum([performance]*[weighting])/100 AS expr1
FROM GOAL
WHERE GOAL.[ID]=[MYID] AND [YEAR]=[MYYEAR] and cat = "cat2"
);
```

When I run the query it asks me to enter myid and myyear. Then it gives me the expected result.

I have a report and would like to have the result of the query at the end of the report. As I put in the query as the source for the textbox and open the report, then the report asks me for one parameter for the report and shows #Fehler (probably #Error with english settings). How can I give the query the parameter from values of the report?

Comment: AFAIK, textbox ControlSource cannot have an SQL statement. Options: 1) subreport; 2) DLookup() expression in textbox.

Comment: When you open a report, usually from a loading form where you collect parameters from the user, you can pass a parameter.  Here is a link for the usual way to pass a parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programmatically