# SUM of same data in access report based on 2 column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

How can I count how many rows have same data in 2 columns on an access report?

This report is always changing based on selections that are made by the user in a combo box and a list box. I want to do the coding in the report. is it possible?

Comment: Do you want Sum or Count? Maybe textbox in report footer: =Count(IIf([field1]=[field2],1,Null))

Comment: this is link to same question but more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54761043/11048470

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking for rows that have duplicate data across columns 1 and 2.  So if in the first row column1 = a and column2 = b, and in another row column1 = a and column2 = b, then we have a duplicate row regardless of other columns.  We have found 1 duplicate row.
Access has a find duplicates wizard under the create- query wizard tabs.  Playing around with the wizard I got a count of rows with the same data.  we subtract 1 to get the number of duplicate rows.  Then I had to go to the sql pane of the designer to quickly wrap that query in a sum to get SumDuplicates.  The resulting sql which give the total number of duplicate rows is:

```
SELECT Sum(Duplicates) as SumDuplicates
FROM
(
SELECT Count([column1])-1 AS Duplicates
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.column1, Table1.column2
HAVING (((Count(Table1.column1))>1) AND ((Count(Table1.column2))>1))
);
```

Adust column and table names to fit your database structure

Comment: hi @mazoula . i know abt query wizard that can find duplicate value but idk how to apply it in access report based on user selection.  this is link to same question but more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54761043/11048470

Comment: You can pass parameters from a form to a report. Then you could use this sql. here is a link to how to pass 1 parameter.  If you want to pass more parameters the easiest way is to append the parameters into one string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programmatically

Comment: hi @mazoula. I kinda get it what you mean. Can you asist me ? i get one idea which is can i make the search button in machine Allocation form that contain pivot1234 subform  as public sub. then i create another button in report pivot1234 and in that button i call that public sub and i put the sql statement in there. but i kinda lost how i want to continue the sql statement.

Comment: I'll take a look at the problem at work tomorrow morning but if you are having trouble parsing the parameters here is a link that shows how to do that: https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/openargs/index.htm

Comment: Thanks mazoula. I already got another alternative to solve my question. Im using group sort total at the bottom of report design. Thank you so much!